# Trouble installing simulation package in Google Colab

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory

Both `!pip install simulation` and `!pip3 install simulation` are failing on my Colab instance.

Both are giving me

```
 Failed building wheel for scikit-sparse
 Running setup.py clean for scikit-sparse
 Failed to build scikit-sparse
 ...
 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried `!pip install scikit-sparse==0.4.4` and I'm getting the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this unblock you?

```
!apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev && pip install scikit-sparse==0.4.4
```